# How to check "storage Value" of "ink!" in latest "Polkadot/Substrate Portal"

Tags: substrate

1. I followed the substrate tutorial and ran the "cargo contract new
   flipper" command.
2. I created a wasm file and a metadata.json file with "ink!" and
   uploaded them on the chain.
3. I have deployed.
4. I would like to call "send as RPC call" as described on this site
   (https://substrate.dev/substrate-contracts-workshop/#/0/calling-your-contract).
   However, the latest "Polakadot/Substrate Portal"
   (https://polkadot.js.org/apps) does not have "send as RPC call".

Please tell me how to check the value of storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I use Substrate rc-5 version.
- I can not use "Send RPC Call" now. ## 2020/8/15
- But I down grade Substrate to rc-4.
- I can use it.